# How do I set the price/plan id in Stripe during migration of accounts?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

From Stripe's migration documentation on [Recreate subscriptions and plans after moving customer data to a new Stripe account](https://support.stripe.com/questions/recreate-subscriptions-and-plans-after-moving-customer-data-to-a-new-stripe-account), this is what they said:

> Recreate your products and plans on the new account. This can be done in the Dashboard or using the Stripe API. When recreating the plans, specify the same id for each plan as on your former account.

When I tried to do so, it gives me this error:
`Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameter: id`.

The code is:

```
price = Stripe::Price.create(
  {
    id: 'price_xxxxxx',
    product: 'prod_xxxxx',
    unit_amount: 1199,
    currency: 'usd',
    recurring: { interval: 'year' },
  }
)
```

There is no way to do it via the dashboard either.

FYI, I am able to actually set the ID of the product, but not the price/plan. Stripe calls price/plan interchangeably now.

Does anyone know how I can set the ID of the price so I can recreate subscriptions on a new Stripe account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set the `id` field when creating a new Price object via the API. The recommendation is to instead relate the *new* object with the *old* object via the [`lookup_key`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-lookup_key).

There is support to set the `id` field when creating a Price via the Dashboard, however you will need to reach out to [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) about having that enabled on your account.

Comment: Thank you. Can you refer to the Stripe docs where the id can be set on the dashboard via support? I searched and can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The comment you're citing mentions Plans and Products, not Prices.

And based on docs, creating Products does allow optional `id` parameter: https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create same for Plans (https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create).

Comment: Thank you. Stripe doc for Plans says that you can use Prices now. "You can now model subscriptions more flexibly using the Prices API. It replaces the Plans API and is backwards compatible to simplify your migration." So, that to me means that plans and prices are synonymous. https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans.

Comment: They might be functionality synonymous, but it looks like they're APIs are not identical. IDK if there's work to bring them closer together...

Comment: The Plans API is backwards compatible, FWIW. But the general recommendation is to migrate to the Prices API where possible.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. What a mess this is. I think it's impossible now and to just ignore that part of their migration docs.

Comment: Yeah, Stripe has the best and the worst system. They are putting a lot of work into decent docs and the test env is one of the best I ever used. But they have enough legacy system going on, and with most of it being exposed as a public API - it's not easy to refactor. In any case - good luck with the migration, @oky_sabeni !

Comment: Thanks Greg. Yes, i'll share more here when i'm done and hopefully others can learn from it.